# Множество Toggle-элементов на одной странице

Tags: jquery

На одной странице множество дивов с айди-wrap, в них есть h3 и ещё див с классом-text, который по умолчанию дисплэй ноун. Надо чтобы по клику на h3 див-text именно в том wrap в котором h3 на который щёлкнули, открывался. Пишу примитивный скрипт jQuery:

```
var wrap = $('#wrap');
wrap.find('h3').click(function(){
    wrap.find('.text').slideToggle();
});
```

Но почему то, это работает только с первым wrap, остальные щёлкаешь и нулевая реакция...
Направьте, на путь истинный...

Comment: _множество дивов с айди-wrap_ - вот причина. В соответствии со спецификацие id должен быть уникален, поэтому никто не гарантирует как будут обрабатываться элементы с одинаковыми id. Используй класс `.wrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*множество дивов с айди-wrap* - вот причина. В соответствии со спецификацие id должен быть уникален, поэтому никто не гарантирует как будут обрабатываться элементы с одинаковыми id. Используй класс `.wrap`

И сразу надо будет править ошибку того, что выбраны сразу все врапперы

```
var wrap = $('.wrap'); // все элементы с классом на странице
wrap.find('h3').click(function(){
    // здесь нужно идти отродителя с классом wrap
    $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.text').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогли. Думал айди для js лучше, а тут вон оно что. Ещё раз благодарю.

Comment: @overtheman, что значит лучше? :-) лучше это понятие относительное

Comment: Да уж, я видимо, как человек без технического образования, а с гуманитарным, понимаю слово "лучше", совсем иначе. Я думал к айди у js больше "душа" лежит, чем к классу -=))

Comment: @overtheman, не, js абсолютно плевать класс это или id